# How to prevent accordion animation in Foundation 6

Tags: javascript, events, zurb-foundation, accordion, zurb-foundation-6

I'm trying to create a form that uses accordions for organization using Foundation 6. I want to add inputs and buttons to the accordion title. Normally when the accordion title is clicked it, it toggles its content by sliding. I want to disable this effect, so that if I click the button in the title the content won't toggle, since it's really annoying if it expands and contracts every time I click the button.

I have something like:

```
    $body.on('click', '.button_on_title', function (event) {
      // do stuff
    });
```

I've tried `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`, and they have no effect. It seems like Foundation 6 is somehow overriding the event stack?

Edit: 
To clarify, I want to prevent the accordion from opening and closing when clicked, not just remove the sliding animation.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the slide speed to `0` to disable the animation. One easy way to set the slide speed is through the `data-slide-speed` data attribute.

Here is the example from the docs with this attribute added:

```
<ul class="accordion" data-accordion data-slide-speed="0">
  <li class="accordion-item is-active">
    <a class="accordion-title">Accordion 1</a>
    <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
      I would start in the open state, due to using the `is-active` state class.
    </div>
  </li>
  <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I actually want to prevent the accordion from expanding when clicked, so setting the speed to 0 doesn't solve this.

Comment: I guess I'm confused. Why are you using an accordion if you don't want something that opens and closes? That's what accordions are for.

Comment: Yes but I want to put an text input field/button on the accordion title. If you click the accordion bar, it should open/close, but if you focus on the text input or click a button on the bar, it shouldn't.